# MS Access: Binding detail controls from a combo box

Tags: ms-access

I want to handle the change event of a combo box and filter the detail controls data based on the selected value of the combo box.  How to?

Answer (score 1):

Combo boxes have various events, the After Update event may suit your purposes. You can use the form filter, however,  if you are not familiar with VBA, it may be easiest to use the wizard to create a combo that finds a record based on the combobox selection.

Comment: One bad thing is that the find combo box wizard produces really crap code that could lead to errors (it doesn't explicitly force the save of the current record if it's dirty).